# how to do echo from a string, only from values that are between a specific stretch[href tag] of the string?

Tags: php, replace, substring, preg-match

[PHP]I have a variable for storing strings (a BIIGGG page source code as string), I want to echo only interesting strings (that I need to extract to use in a project, dozens of them), and they are inside the quotation marks of the tag `<a href="HERE"></a>`

but I just want to capture the values that start with the letter: N (news)

```
[<a href="/news7044449/exclusive_news_sunday_"]
<a href="/n[ews7044449/exclusive_news_sunday_]"
that is, I think you will have to work with match using: [a href="/n]
```

how to do that to define that the echo will delete all the texts of the variable, showing only:

note that there are other hrefs tags with values that start with other letters, such as the letter 'P' : **href="/profiles...** (This does not interest me.)

```
$string = '</div><span class="news-hd-mark">HD</span></div><p><a href="/news7044449/exclusive_news_sunday_" title="exclusive_news_sunday_">exclusive_news_sunday_</a></p><p class="metadata"><span class="bg"><a href="/profiles/czechav">Czech AV</a><span class="mobile-hide"> - 5.4M Views</span>
- <span class="duration">7 min</span></span></p></div><script>xv.thumbs.preparenews(7044449);</script>                                      
<div id="news_31720715" class="thumb-block "><div class="thumb-inside"><div class="thumb"><a href="/news31720715/my_sister_running_every_single_morning"><img src="https://static-hw.xnewss.com/img/lightbox/lightbox-blank.gif"';
```

I imagine something like this:

```
$removes_everything_except_values_from_the_href_tag_starting_with_the_letter_n = ('/something regex expresion I think /' or preg_match, substring?);
    echo $string = str_replace($removes_everything_except_values_from_the_href_tag_starting_with_the_letter_n,'',$string);
```

**expected output:** `/news7044449/exclusive_news_sunday_`

NOTE: it is not essential to be through a variable, it can be from a .txt file the place where the extracts will be extracted, and not necessarily a variable.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will help her.

```
<?php

$source = file_get_contents("code.html");

preg_match_all("/<a href=\"(\/n(?:.+?))\"[^>]*>/", $source, $results);

var_export( end($results) );
```

Step by Step Regex:

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xauopg/1)**

**[Regex Debugger](https://regex101.com/r/Xauopg/1/debugger)**

Comment: thank you so much @Valdeir Psr for you reply! There is little left for me to accept your reply, you really understood my question and actually found the solution, but for one of my deficiencies, I do not know how to make the clean exit as I asked in the question( just `/news7044449/exclusive_news_sunday_` ), but 90% is answered by you. please, see you here in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/5G8C0NEi

Answer (score 1):

To get just the links out of the $results array from Valdeir's answer:

```
foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo $r;

    // alt: to display them with an HTML break tag after each one
    echo $r."<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much friend :)  `//var_export( end($results) );
//var_dump( end($results) );
$array = end($results);

foreach ($array as $r) {
   echo $r."<br>\n";
}`